# How to do to display timing for the result's items found in MVC3(C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, timing

Please someone teach me how to display timing (seconds) for the search result in MVC3(C#). I searched but don't know how to do or what function I have to use on MVC3. I attached image file that I would like to display. [Here the image file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSOqm.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No. Just I put it that I want to show to you and wanted to display like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you would use a System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch to record your execution time and place it into the ViewBag. You then print the value stored in the ViewBag on your page.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it now.